# Response option with Telegram Bot and Node-Red

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-red

I am programming a Telegram bot with Node-Red and I have found a problem.

To manage the replies I use telegram reply passing it the messageID of the message I sent before. But it makes me very uncomfortable having to continually select "Reply" to be able to maintain the conversation.
I have seen that in other bots, when they send a message it is automatically selected to reply, in this way the user does not have to select the received message since the bot does it automatically. Does anybody know how it's done?

I've been looking at the documentation of "node-red-contrib-telegrambot(it's the one I use)" but I can't find anything.

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a finite state machine on your Node-RED and use simple Receiver nodes instead of Reply ones. Be careful: the Receivers will all receive the same message at the same time, so you have to implement a finite state machine in order to let only one Receiver work. Add a sort of 'filter' node right after the Receiver node and the job is done